# Add specific class to ul that contains the current page link

Tags: jquery, html, url

I have the following HTML code:

```
 <li><a href="index.php"> Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="manageArticles.php"> Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="addArticle.php"> More...</a></li>
```

I need to add the class `active` to the `li` that contains the link of the cirrent page.

For axample in the page `index.php` for the second `li` tag should added the class active.

I have a script code that gets the current URL:

```
 var currentPageName = document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
```

But I don't really know what should I do after this (and if it's even possible)..

Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: In my test the regex wasn't working so I used: window.location.pathname

Comment: `$('li a[href="'+currentPageName+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active')`

Comment: you really need it to be javascript? that kind of stuff is better handled server-side checking the request_uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` function to get `li`s which contain `a` with `href`-attr which is equal to `currentPageName`;

```
var currentPageName = document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$( 'li' )
    .filter(function() { return $( 'a' , this ).attr( 'href' ) === currentPageName; } )
    .addClass( 'active' );
```